# Writing to the serial _input_ port - not the output port

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, serial-port, blocking

I have a thread that waits for serial communications with this structure:
(*InputStream* is SerialPort.BaseStream)

```
while ((bytesRead = InputStream.Read(RxBuffer, RxBufferIndex, 20)) > 0)
{
    // read and handle data

    if ((ShouldStop) || (!HasSource))
        break;
}
```

The problem is that unless I receive some serial data - I can't exit the blocking call, and don't exit the thread.
I don't want to `Abort()` the thread - it's an ugly solution.

If I write to my *InputStream* the serial port abstraction redirects my data to the output port (as you would normally want).

How can I write 25 bytes to the *input* port so my read happens, and the program flow continues?

Comment: You can try to set read timeout or use async read

Comment: Usually, to terminate blocking reads, one makes another thread *close* the stream which should abort any blocking calls upon it, signalling an appropriate error/exception.

Comment: For debug you can install emulator (some com port emulators can make pair wired com ports for test) or use com cable with mirror stub

Comment: You're asking an XY question that is illogical (write to input port) and not the correct (or even feasible) solution to the root problem.  If the serial port is configured for canonical reads, then you have to wait for a line-termination character (as defined by the line discipline in use).  If you don't want to wait for a line-termination character, then maybe the serial port should be configured for non-canonical (aka raw) input.  You can then setup the read to terminate on various combinations of timeout and/or number of bytes available/requested.